# Computing a tensor product

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $\phi: B \rightarrow A$ be a ring homomorphism and so $A$ becomes a $B$-module via this map. Let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal of $B$.  Is there a simple description of $A \otimes_B \textrm{Frac} (B/\mathfrak p)$? For instance, when $\mathfrak p$ is maximal then this equals  $A/ (\phi ( \mathfrak p)  \cdot A)$ but I am not sure how to compute this in general. Could somebody please help me out?

Comment: In general, this is the localization $(A/\mathfrak{p}A)_{(0)}$ where $(0)$ is the zero ideal of $B/\mathfrak{p}$. Can you prove it? Also, if you know any algebraic geometry: can you give a geometric interpretation of this result?

Comment: Since you are localizing $A/\mathfrak p A$, could you clarify the statement that (0) is a prime ideal of $B/ \mathfrak p$?

Comment: Not a typo – $A/\mathfrak{p}A$ has a natural $B/\mathfrak{p}$-module structure, so it makes sense to localize $A/\mathfrak{p}A$ with respect to any multiplicative subset of $B/\mathfrak{p}$, including $(B/\mathfrak{p}) \setminus \{0\}$. It might be a good idea to begin by defining this $B/\mathfrak{p}$-module structure.

Comment: Using $S^{-1}M=S^{-1}R \otimes_R M$,  we get $(A/\mathfrak p A)_{(0)}=\textrm{Frac} (B/\mathfrak p) \otimes_{B/\mathfrak p} A/ \mathfrak p A$.  How do I proceed further?

Answer (score 0):

$\require{AMScd}$ First, observe that $A/\mathfrak{p}A\cong A\otimes_B B/\mathfrak{p}$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742473/tensor-product-of-quotient-rings) if you're not familiar). Now,  abstract nonsense tells us that $A\otimes_B\operatorname{Frac}(B/\mathfrak{p})\cong A/\mathfrak{p}A\otimes_{B/\mathfrak{p}}\operatorname{Frac}(B/\mathfrak{p}),$ because both inner squares in the commutative diagram
\begin{CD}
B @>>> B/\mathfrak{p} @>>> \operatorname{Frac}(B/\mathfrak{p}) \\
@VVV \lrcorner @VVV \lrcorner @VVV\\
A @>>> A/\mathfrak{p}A @>>> A/\mathfrak{p}A\otimes_{B/\mathfrak{p}}\operatorname{Frac}(B/\mathfrak{p})
\end{CD}
are pushouts (this implies the outer square is a pushout as well). You've already seen why $A/\mathfrak{p}A\otimes_{B/\mathfrak{p}}\operatorname{Frac}(B/\mathfrak{p})\cong S^{-1}(A/\mathfrak{p}A),$ where $S= B/\mathfrak{p}\setminus\{0\},$ so this proves the desired isomorphism.